# Couldn't receive any data using jQuery AJAX in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using `CakePHP 1.26`.

I was trying to use `jQuery Ajax` to pass some sample data to a function in a Controller but failed to do it.

This is the jQuery part:

```
 var w="helloworld";
 var curl="http://localhost:8080/test/grab/";
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: curl,
     data: "testing="+w,   
     success: function(data) {    
         alert(data);
     }
 });
```

And this is the function of the Controller:

```
function grab() {
    $g=$this->data['testing'];
    return $g;
}
```

But the `alert` msg box did not show me anything but a blank message.

Please help if you could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->data` is only filled with data in the format `data[key]=value`. In this case, your AJAX call's data property should look like this:

```
data: "data[testing]=" + w
```

To pass more than one, simply separate with an ampersand:

```
data: "data[one]=" + one + "&data[two]=" + two
```

Finally, you can actually nest them, like so:

```
data: "data[0][one]" = one[0] + "&data[0][two]=" + one[1] + "&data[1]=" + data
```

This will make `$this->data` a multi-dimensional array.